# Can't open the desktop app created with PyInstaller

Tags: python, encoding, syntax-error, pyqt4, pyinstaller

I created a PyIinstaller file from a `.py` file. In this file, I've got files with the `.ui` extension created using PyQt4. But when I try to execute the file created, it shows this error:

```
File "C:\Users\Flosh\Desktop\dist\ProgramNew\New.exe", line 1
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\x90' in file C:\Users\Flosh\Desktop\dist\ProgramNew\New.exe on line 1, 
but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
```

In the original `.py` file, I use the UTF-8 encoding, but this error shows an ASCII problem.

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Do you added this one in original python code file? http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, I did use those lines in my code.

Comment: Your python file is not saved as UTF-8

Comment: Do you have `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the top of your file?

Comment: Maybe you have BOM ( U+FEFF BYTE ORDER MARK) in begin of file. Remove it. https://gist.github.com/ZiTAL/1b011032616a5b3bf7e6

Comment: SOrry for late reply. Yes, i do have at the beggining the line: '-*- coding: utf-8 -*-'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a Python traceback, but the first line is showing an *exe file*:

```
File "C:\Users\Flosh\Desktop\dist\ProgramNew\New.exe", line 1
```

which suggests you must be trying to run the application like this:

```
python C:\Users\Flosh\Desktop\dist\ProgramNew\New.exe
```

You cannot run exe files with Python. Indeed, the whole point of using tools like PyInstaller is that you don't even need to have Python installed in order to run the program. You have created a *self-contained executable*, so just run it directly, like this:

```
C:\Users\Flosh\Desktop\dist\ProgramNew\New.exe
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try cxfreeze for creating the installer or executable package. Description of creating the setup file is given  [here](https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/distutils.html). May be this could help you.

Answer (score 1):

As @Hisham Karam already said in his comment to your question, you probably have not saved your file with the utf-8 encoding. Just adding `# coding: utf-8` at the top of your python file is not enough, it also *has to be encoded in utf-8*. There are many ways to  check this, my preferred is to use [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/):

[image]